# Determining the Level of Hierarchy in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a data of an ERP Standard Feature called Bill of Material, Where It'll have a tree Structure.

I has 4 column as Unique_Id,from,is_main and srno

So here 1st Column is an unique Id,2nd Column indicated its Parent row, 3rd Column Indicates whether it has a sub set or not and 4th is just another series of the Subset.

Link for the Screenshots : [Screenshots](http://sdrv.ms/1epWadA)

So Picture indicates the Hierarchy of the above data.

So I need to get the Answer as Level of Hierarchy. As picture shows the Maximum of 4 stages of Hierarchy.

Comment: sounds like it might be something in connection with an OLAP cube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Sample query, You have to change according to you

```
WITH temp AS 
(
    SELECT A.Unique_Id, A.from, A.is_main , A.srno
    FROM [dbo].[Your_Table_Name] A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT B.Unique_Id, A.from, B.is_main , B.srno
    FROM temp AS B

    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Your_Table_Name] A ON B.from= A.Unique_Id

    WHERE A.from IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM  temp
```

Comment: I've explained you about only one table. your query has two table in it. Can you just clarify me please

Comment: It's not two table..CategoryRec is alias table of Category. It's all onle about Category table. Please check well

Comment: I have updated solution with your table structure please run this query

Comment: Bro, i'm not getting it. Where's the field to show the Level.?